Is there a way to store YAML specification in RStudio?
I am using Quarto framework inside RStudio to prepare reports. My reports have consistent format. So, I would like to store its YAML specification somewhere. In current setup, I have to copy and paste the YAML specification from the previous report. Is it possible to store it somewhere in RStudio? I have tried to store it in a code snippet, but it also shows errors lately.
The YAML specifications are as follows:
format:
    html:
      theme: cosmo
    pdf:
      number-sections: true
      number-depth: 3
      documentclass: scrbook
      classoption: ["paper =a4", "twoside", "openright", "headsepline", "footsepline", "listof = totocnumbered", "chapterprefix = true", "firstiscover"]
      include-in-header:
        - file: preamble.tex
      geometry:
        - top=1in
        - bottom=1in
        - left=1in
        - right=1in
        - heightrounded
      colorlinks: true
      toc: true
      toc-title: "Contents"
      lot: true
      lof: true
      fig-cap-location: bottom
      fig-align: center
      fig-width: 6.5
      fig-pos: 'h'
      linestretch: 2
      tbl-cap-location: top
      code-line-numbers: true
      code-block-bg: EFEFEF
      keep-tex: true
      link-citations: true
      nocite: |
        @*
      author-meta: "Eva"
      title-meta: "Title of the Report"
      hyperrefoptions:
        - linktoc=all
        - pdfwindowui
        - pdfpagemode=FullScreen
  execute: 
    echo: true
    warning: false
    message: false
    error: false
    cache: true

Ideally, I would like to store it in a package, where I can apply a function, and it would output as a properly formatted YAML file. Is it possible to do this?

You could perhaps create a report template.  Use the params section of the YAML header to define what changes between reports.  The use a small driver program to define the parameters and then call quarto_render to produce the reports...

It's not a bad idea, @Limey, but the issue is that this is not a repetitive job. I prepare multiple reports, in different frequencies. So, I will have different RStudio projects for them. That's why I am looking for a way to store the specification somewhere, so that I don't have to copy paste every time.

Ok.  That's useful context.  In that case, just create a skeleton quarto file with the YAML and any other common content and use that as the starting point for each new file.  Just Save as... as the first action every time you start.  Depending on just how much the different reports differ, it may even be worth investing the time in creating a template report that will vary its contents based on different input parameters.  The best way to do that needs context that you haven't given us.

Since to want to put it in a package, just create a function that uses, say, writeLines to write the header to file whose name you specify (and whose extension would presumably be .qmd)...
